# What color does the Stock Android Browser use as it's default background color?

Tags: android, android-layout

What color does the Stock Android Browser use as it's default background color?

When I check google.com using my Samsung Tab running Android 4.1.2, it get a pleasant color (see the red squares below). The same thing changes to something else, when I take a screen shot, and then it's again something else when I view it on my desktop changing user agents.

What is the hex value of the color that it uses?

[image: Screen Capture - Android Stock Browser]

[image: Screen Capture - Firefox Windows 7 with edited user agent]

[image: Nice pleasant shade when running on Androids Stock Browser]

Comment: Take a screen shot and test the color with a bitmap editor.

Comment: Its one color on-screen, another in the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

It is `#EEEEEE`

This website might help: [Color Picker Online](http://imagecolorpicker.com/)

Comment: #EEEEEE Is the actual coded color. But when it's viewed on Android, it doesn't look the same as the way it does on a desktop. Does Android change the color?

Comment: The difference might due to the display of the phone. Different phones have different deviation to the origin color. In another word, RED in Nexus 4 might looks different from RED in Galaxy S4